# Payment Timeouts - Showing 504 Gateway Timeout

Tags: paypal, timeout

We have a cpouple of sites using website payments standard and are submitting the forms as a post to the https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr address

some customers (not all) are experiencing a timeout when trying to get to the paypal payment page after the post.

The site sits and status bar says 'waiting for www.paypal.com'
The web Inspector on chrome shows a 504 Gateway Timeout error after 1 minute and then the user gets sent to a paypal page with a paypal debug-id down at the bottom

This is intermittent, sometimes there are no problems at all then sometimes a user cant get through, so we try at the same time and have no problem

has anyone else seen anything like this?

any ideas?

paypal support are 'looking into it' and said it couldb e a 'problem with our endpoint api' ... all we do is post to them and and then they send back a pdt/ipn when complete. and it works from different locations at the same time one person is down, someone accross thr country is fine, its like when there is a problem, the www.paypal.com address cannot be found by the browser trying to connect

Answer (score 0):

You are not alone. The old PayPal webform integration seems to have this problem every now and then. I believe there is nothing you can do other than hope that your customers are not affected (much).

The only alternative is to use a different PayPal API to integrate it in your shop.